# Mismatch vue package error in nuxtjs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am getting an error while trying to run my project on dev mode.

```
user@Apples-MacBook-Pro myproject (hotfix/carousel-2) $ npm run dev

> myproject@1.0.0 dev /Users/user/nuxt-projects/myproject
> nuxt

/Users/user/nuxt-projects/myproject/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/index.js:8
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.16
- vue-server-renderer@2.5.13
```

I tried deleting the node_modules directory and re-run npm insatll, but still getting the same error. Could you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: change version of `vue-server-renderer` to 2.5.16 manually.

Comment: Do u have vue-server-render in your package.json? Deleting it should work

Answer (score 2):

I solved same problem with deleting cache files and package lock files.

```
rm -rf package-lock.json && npm cache clean
```

If you used yarn instead of npm, then

```
rm -rf yarn.lock && yarn cache clean
```

After removing lock files, install again

```
npm install
```

OR

```
yarn install --network-timeout 600000
```

Later, it might solve same problems.

Comment: As of `npm@5`, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use `'npm cache verify'` instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with `--force`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got it to work by using:

1. `rm -rf node_modules/` // Removes node_modules folder
2. `rm -rf package-lock.json && npm cache clean --force` //Removes package-lock file and cleans cache forcefully (npm v5+)
3. `npm install` // do a fresh install

Thanks [@luiseok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52368984/3163075)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm audit fix --force
```

> This command is the quick fix for your question